# automator: sorting image with ocr

Tags: macos, automator, automation, image-processing, ocr

I have a folder with screenshots of a document, in every image I have an article number in the same exact position. Ideally, I would like something in a text file or to add to numbers table.

what is the favorable approach to take in order to perform this action?

I thought about mash slicing those images only to the specific area of information

then use Create ML image classifier but I couldn't really understand the next steps

[image: example]

Comment: The answer to the overwhelming majority of questions which start *Is it possible to ...* is *Yes*.  Which is no help to you at all.  But what help do you expect ?  Do you want help to write software for your task ?  Do you want recommendations for software you might use for your task ?

Comment: I would like to have a recommendation for the easiest way to do it.
I thought about mash slicing all the pictures to the exact measurement of the title and somehow use create ml